# WebAPI route regex with optional parts

Tags: regex, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I want to map a WebAPI action method to urls on the format `api/v2/l8n/{cultureCode}`, but to avoid route collisions with other methods, I need to constrain the `cultureCode` parameter to only values matching the regex `^\w{2}(?:-\w{2})?$`, i.e. `sv` and `en-GB`, but not `hello`.

I have a `RoutePrefix` attribute on the controller that takes care of `api/v2/i8n`, so I tried mapping the action with

```
[Route(@"{cultureString:regex(^\w{2}(?:-\w{2})?$)")]
```

but then an error was thrown at configuration time stating that `{cultureString:regex(^\w{2` was a bad route value. I tried replacing `\w{2}` with `\w\w` as well as removing the `@` and escaping my backslashes, but was then instead presented with

> The route template cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.

If I can't even use `?`, how can I ever create a regex with an optional part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do hope there is no such limitation on the pipeline operator or alternation operator, using which and some anchors, you could get it to work.

```
[Route(@"{cultureString:regex(^\w\w(-\w{2}|)$)}")]
```

What the above means is that it matches either two `\w` followed by another two `\w` or end of the string, `$`

Comment: now it matches `dd-ddd` also. I suggest you to use `^\w\w(-\w{2}|)$`

Comment: Could have worked, but unfortunately it didn't: `The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: 'regex(^\w\w(-\w\w|)$'`. Any ideas how to go on from this?

Comment: Nvm; the posted solution was missing an ending parenthesis and curly brace, opened by `{...:regex(` - adding them, it works =) (I've edited the answer to include this change.)

Comment: @TomasLycken oh sorry, wasn't able to reply as I was in school. Anyway, glad to see that you were able to solve the problem.